# HOW to fix 'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied' in python-crontab in docker image?

Tags: python, docker

I create a docker image in order to set a python code with schedule,so I use `python-crontab` module, how can i solve permission denied problem?

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
python 3.5.2

I create `sche.py` and it can trigger `weather.py`,
it is success in local,but it can't package to docker image

````
```
#dockerfile
FROM python:3.5.2

WORKDIR /weather
ENTRYPOINT ["/weather"]

ADD . /weather
RUN chmod u+x sche.py
RUN chmod u+x weather.py

RUN mkdir /usr/bin/crontab    
#add due to /usr/bin/crontab not found
RUN pip3  install python-crontab 

RUN pip3  install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80
#ENV NAME World

CMD ["sudo"]
#CMD  ["python", "sche.py"] ## build step fail
ENTRYPOINT ["python","sche.py"]  
## can build same as "RUN ["python","sche.py"] "
```
````

I expect it can run in docker image rather than each python file only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `USER root` after `FROM python:3.5.2` line.

Remove `CMD ["sudo"]` and `ENTRYPOINT ["/weather"]`

#### Updated

Replace `RUN mkdir /usr/bin/crontab`

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y cron \
    && apt-get autoremove -y
```

Comment: thanks for your advise, but I try it in first time, it still can not run

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sche.py", line 4, in <module>
    my_cron = CronTab(user= True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/crontab.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.read(tabfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/crontab.py", line 284, in read
    (out, err) = open_pipe(CRONCMD, l='', **self.user_opt).communicate()

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/crontab.py", line 189, in open_pipe
    return sp.Popen(args, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, env=env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: why do you want to create crontab folder `RUN mkdir /usr/bin/crontab` ?

Comment: if i didn't create:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/crontab'

Comment: i also try pip instead of pip3

Comment: Then you have to install `crontab` - See my updated answer

Comment: if i change to CMD  ["python", "sche.py"]
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/weather\": permission denied": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled

Comment: Remove `ENTRYPOINT ["/weather"]`

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/#description
if i install it:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
it will same as the link says:
Note: If you get the error TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments when using CronTab, you have the wrong module installed. You need to install python-crontab and not crontab from pypi or your local package manager and try again.

Comment: Update the final Dockerfile you have now. `ENTRYPOINT ["/weather"]` is not needed, as /weather is a folder and not executable, right?